# Не сохраняется список в БД

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Создаю чеклист, добавляю в БД:

[image: Create]

Считываю из БД -- список пустой, все остальное на месте:

[image: Details]

**Модель**

```
public class Checklist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Check> Checks { get; set; }
}

public class Check
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Контроллер**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Checks")] Checklist checklist)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Checklists.Add(checklist);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(checklist);
}


public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Checklist checklist = db.Checklists.Find(id);
    if (checklist == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(checklist);
}
```

Comment: записываете с `id = 0`, загружаете с `id = 6`

Comment: Id -- идентификатор в БД, я его не заношу сам

Comment: а, у вас там брейпоинт до сохранения стоит и id еще не вернулся?

Comment: ага (12 символов)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что метод `find(id)` загружает только искомую сущность, игнорируя при этом связанные.
Вам необходимо загрузить связанный список через `include` и отфильтровать данные по `id`

```
var cl = db.Checklists.include(c => c.Checks)
              .Where(c => c.id == id)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

либо вы можете все также загрузить запись с помощью `find`, а потом, если она нашлась, подгрузить остатки:

```
var cl = db.Checklists.Find(id);
if(!cl) return HttpNotFound();
db.Entry(cl).Collection(c => c.Checks).Load();
```

а также у вас в запасе есть еще ленивая загрузка. Когда данные будут извлечены при необходимости при первом обращении к ним.